# Returning expired I-94

Tags: i-94

I returned to Canada from USA and the I-94 was not collected at the border. It has now expired. I can see my departure has been correctly noted on the CBP website: https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search.

Do I still need to return the expired I-94? If yes, can I just drive down to the border and hand it over instead of mailing it with all proofs?

Comment: If you live in Canada, and the I94 website is showing correctly that you've left, I see no problem with just leaving it as-is and not returning the expired I94.  I live in Mexico, so no record is ever kept of me leaving the US (so my exit never shows on the I94 website), and I have never had any issues crossing back into the US and obtaining a new I94 when required.  Of course things may be treated in a different manner at the northern border, which is why I haven't posted an answer as I've got nothing to support it

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of returning the I-94W form is to have your departure recorded. If your departure was recorded electronically (and correctly) there is no need to bother with returning the paper.